# unable to click on button

Tags: iphone

am creating login application for both orientation,

First loginController works fine for both orientation, but next view i.e. updateController creates problem.

I created two views for updateController as LandscapeView and PortraitView.

In IB i link 'PortraitView' to File's Owner 'view', so that it's work fine but when my orientation is changed to 'LandscapeView' then it's loaded fine but can't click buttons on it.

Why does it happens?

Answer (score 0):

Your IBAction methods you invoke with clicking a button most likely is connected with the Interface Builder in one view but not in the other